# Which Entity Framework is used in Visual Studio 2012 with ASP.NET MVC 4 with Windows 7?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, visual-studio-2012

I have seen there is different option when we add Entity Framework for database connection, but those options are not present in ASP.NET MVC 4 in Visual Studio 2012.

Can anyone tell what is the step by step procedure to use database in Visual Studio 2012 with ASP.NET MVC 4 on Windows 7?

Answer (score 0):

You can use entity framework 5.0 with Visual Studio 2012.
Steps-
1.First create your database
2.Add new item "ADO.NET Entity Data Model" which will be creating all the edmx classes.
3.Now you can use save , delete etc functions from these above classes using the reference in your desired classes.